# Model instance not reflecting data passed from pre_save in custom field

Tags: python, django

I have a custom field for generating slug and I am using it in my model.

The strange thing I can't figure out is why is the value I am generating in this custom field's method `pre_save` not set on the current instance.

**My question is not about generating slug different way but about this behavior.**

To simplify this example I defined this classes:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    slug = MyCustomField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'in save'
        print self.slug
```

Field:

```
class MyCustomField(models.SlugField):
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = super(MyCustomField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
        if not value:
            value = 'random-generated-slug'
        return value
```

Post save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def test(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'in signal'
    print kwargs['instance'].slug
    print 'from database'
    print MyModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs['instance'].pk).slug
```

Code to run:

```
instance = MyModel()
instance.save()
>> 'in signal'
>> ''
>> 'in database'
>> 'random-generated-slug'
>> 'in save'
>> ''
instance.slug
>> ''
```

Like you can see, the value is set in the database, but it's not on the current instance nor in post_save signal.

I have Django version 1.10. Should I set the value in a different way in `MyCustomField`? What is going on?

EDIT:
Maybe I should set this value in field's `save_form_data` or where is the best place to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The instance's slug field was updated between the call to save and the write into the database. The current instance's slug value is *stale*

To get the slug value which was written into the DB, the instance has to updated by *refetching* from the database:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=your_pk)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. If I wanted to update the instance in `MyCustomField` do you think the `save_form_data` would be a good place?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking, but I think the instance can't be updated *in-place* and not before it's been written to the DB.